# Arrange Text Properly in testimonial part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need an arrangement shown in the figure, since I cant post images please click on [this link](http://s6.postimg.org/uvdgh7uzl/foto.png).

for the same I have coded as follows

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
                <div class="test-item">
                    <span class="test-head">
                        <img src="images/testimonial_item.png" class="img-responsive" />
                    </span>
                    <p class="test-quote">
                        Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus erat porttitor. 
                        <span class="test-author" >
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="test-author-org">
                           lorem
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .testimonial
    {
        background: #fff;
        padding:60px 0px !important;
        position:relative;
    }
    .test-head {
        float: left;
            width: 10% !important;
    }
    .test-head img
    {
        height:80px;
        width:auto;
        }
        .test-author-org,.test-author
        {
            float:right;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            color:#626262;
            }
            .testimonial p
            {
                padding-right:70px !important;
                }
    .test-item
    {
        background:#e6e6e6;
        border-radius:70px;
        min-height:81px;
    }
.testimonial .test-quote
{
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #0a3980;
    text-align: left;
    padding:10px 0 0 0 ;
    margin-bottom:0px!important;
    clear:right;
}
```

[fiddled here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/bzz06r96/)

how can i make  it exact to the image ?

please help anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from scratch, the below will produce what you are looking for.

**Note** that if your quote will be less than 650px, you may need to tweak the margins, padding, and/or widths so the content doesn't overflow the container.

[See a working jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bzz06r96/3/)

```css
.my-head{
    width:61px;
    float:left;
}
.my-body{
    padding-top:15px;
    width:auto;
    max-width:90%;
    float:left;
}

.my-quote-container {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #0a3980;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px!important;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 70px;
    min-height: 81px;
    clear:both;
    
}
.my-head-img{
    float:left;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 15px;
    margin-right:25px;
}
.my-quote{
    text-align: left;
    display:table;
    padding-right:35px;
    padding-left:35px;
    float:left;
}
.my-body span{
    clear: right; float: right;
    padding-right:42px;
    color:#666666;
}
}
.my-author{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-quote-container">
  <div class="my-item">
    <div class="my-head"> <img src="http://s6.postimg.org/qara2aba5/testimonial_item.png" class="img-responsive my-head-img" /> </div>
    <div class="my-body">
      <div class="my-quote">Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus erat porttitor.</div>
      <br>
      <span class="my-author cap">Lorem Ipsum</span> <br />
      <span class="my-author">lorem</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DelightedDOD I dont understand why are you rotated that image, please check the testimonial author text arrangement , that is what I need, I dont want to rotate the image or nothing

Comment: Im not sure i follow. I rotated the image because the image used points down while the image shown at your link here http://s6.postimg.org/uvdgh7uzl/foto.png is rotated and pointing right. As for the text, I put the wrong link to the jsfiddle (fixed it now). It looks pretty close to what you showed. See http://prntscr.com/6968bw